# Applying Canadian Postal Code areas in shapefile to Google Earth?

Tags: shapefile, google-earth

So for someone who just downloaded and opened Google Earth and then searched for how to view postal codes on google earth this is all very confusing.. I downloaded the Crowdsourced Canadian Postal Code Polygon File Shapefile format As of September 22, 2016. but I don't know what to do with it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I have concerns on the data quality of the postcode polygons, have added an answer if you wish to pursue...

Answer (score 3):

If you have downloaded a shapefile then you should be able to import that into Google Earth Pro but not standard Google Earth as described in [Importing Geographic Information Systems (GIS) data in Google Earth](https://www.google.com.au/earth/outreach/tutorials/importgis.html).

My understanding is that Google Earth Pro can now be [downloaded and installed for free use](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/176160?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the data downloaded from [geocoder.ca](https://geocoder.ca/?freedata=1)?

It seems they only provide the data in a shapefile (.shp) format. Google Earth cannot read and open shapefiles. It can open KMZ, KML, images, GPX and a few more file types. What you'll need to do is convert the shp file into a supported format (probably KMZ). Theres plenty of free and commercial software to do this. A quick google search also indicates there are some websites that'll do this for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Shapefile needs converting to KMZ (this is a large file with 665,055 records)
But the quality of the data is a bigger concern...

[image]

There is a lot of spiking of polygon boundaries and the dataset does not seem complete (have compared with purchased data).

Would not recommend using this dataset in it's current state.

QGIS can do this, but personally this would not be useful as is.
http://www.qgis.org/en/site/

Shape to KML from QGIS results
[image]