# Building a shapefile for Canadian postal codes

Tags: r, shapefile

**Background:** I am working with the R Programming language. I am looking for a shapefile of Canadian Postal Codes - but unfortunately, there is nothing available online for free. Therefore, I had the following idea : I know that there is a free dataset of 10 million fully geocoded Canadian Addresses and each address has a Postal Code and a Longitude/Latitude coordinate. (https://www.statcan.gc.ca/en/lode/databases/oda) - if I were to take all these addresses, perhaps I could somehow try to encircle all longitude/latitude coordinates with the same postal code into their own boundary, and thus derive "approximate" postal code boundaries.

**Introduction:** To approach this problem, I first asked myself the following question:

**Suppose you have 100 longitude/latitude coordinate points - what is the smallest shape that will enclose these 100 points?**

To answer this question, I learned about something called the "**Convex Hull**" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) which is exactly this. Here is an example in R of how to determine the convex hull of a given set of points:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)


# simulate data
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(longitude = runif(n, -180, 180),
                 latitude = runif(n, -90, 90))

# find the convex hull
hull <- chull(df$longitude, df$latitude)
hull <- c(hull, hull[1])

# visualize results
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_polygon(data = df[hull, ], aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), fill = "red", alpha = 0.5)


# optional : convert to shapefile 
hull_df <- df[hull, ]

# optional : convert to shapefile 
hull_sf <- st_as_sf(hull_df, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)
```

[image]

**My Question:** Suppose I have a similar problem - but now are there different "classes" of points (e.g. red class, blue class, green class - these represent the Postal Codes). **Now, I want to identify 3 convex hulls - but I want none of the convex hulls to overlap with each other.**

When I tried to do this:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(longitude = runif(n, -180, 180),
                 latitude = runif(n, -90, 90),
                 color = sample(c("red", "blue", "green"), n, replace = TRUE))

# Find the convex hull of the points for each color class
hulls <- lapply(unique(df$color), function(color) {
  chull(df[df$color == color, c("longitude", "latitude")])
})

# Create scatter plot with convex hulls
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = color)) +
  lapply(seq_along(hulls), function(i) {
    geom_polygon(data = df[df$color == unique(df$color)[i], ][hulls[[i]], ],
                 aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), fill = unique(df$color)[i], alpha = 0.5)
  })


# optional steps
hull_sfs <- lapply(seq_along(hulls), function(i) {
  st_as_sf(df[df$color == unique(df$color)[i], ][hulls[[i]], ],
           coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)
})


hull_sf_combined <- do.call(rbind, hull_sfs)


st_write(hull_sf_combined, "hulls.shp")
```

[image]

**Problem:** As we can see here - the convex hulls for the different color classes were identified, but they all overlap with each other now. **As such, is there any way around this?**

**Note:** Is the "Concave Hull" a better choice for this kind of problem?

```
library(concaveman)

# find concave hull
concave_hull <- concaveman(as.matrix(df))
concave_hull_df <- as.data.frame(concave_hull)
names(concave_hull_df) <- c("x", "y")



# scatter plot with concave hull
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_polygon(data = concave_hull_df, aes(x = x, y = y), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  ggtitle("Concave Hull")
```

**References:**

- [Applying Canadian Postal Code areas in shapefile to Google Earth?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212529/applying-canadian-postal-code-areas-in-shapefile-to-google-earth)

Comment: The ODA data is only a small fraction of the real number of postcodes take a look at the Saskatchewan csv it only has data for two cities (Regina and Saskatoon) https://download.geonames.org/export/zip/ (CA_Full.zip) might be a better starting point.

Comment: @ Mapperz: thank you so much for your reply! This is the first time I have heard of geonames. what exactly is this? thanks!

Comment: more background on geonames https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoNames

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are going to get anywhere with concave hulls (or even convex hulls) for this.

If you compute the Voronoi polygon for each point, and then dissolve based on the set of polygons with the same code, you'll get a feature per-code, with no overlap. Each feature contains the area for which the nearest postcode point is of that code.

Notice I say "feature" and not "polygon". This method does not guarantee a single polygon ring per postcode. If you have two points for the same code scattered in a sea of other codes, then the feature for that code will contain two islands. It would be a very hard problem to generate a single polygon ring in this case, if indeed its possible.

Comment: @ spacedman: thank you so much for your answer! if you have time - can you please show me how to do this? I will start attempting this in the meantime.

Comment: here is my attempt: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/464801/using-voroni-polygons-to-build-a-shapefile-of-canadian-postal-codes

Comment: just a question : "I don't think you are going to get anywhere with concave hulls (or even convex hulls) for this." ... why do you think so? I would be interested to hear your logic. thanks!

Comment: Hulls for two different postcodes will be generated independently of each other, so there may be overlap which you then have to deal with. And that overlap could contain points of either type, or no points at all. There might be a way to intersect and do something with the overlapping areas but it could get horribly deep quickly...

Comment: thank you for your reply! are there any "approximate" quick fixes to this kind of problem (that might result in minor violations, i.e. intersection between hulls)? can this be done approximately well using voroni diagrams? if you have time, could you please show me how to do this? thank you so much!

Comment: Depends on how mixed up the point classes are. You try drawing polygons that enclose the three sets of points in the example in your question.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this related question if you have time? thank you so much https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/465897/what-does-it-mean-to-clip-a-polygon

Comment: No need to ask, if its tagged [r] I'll see it!